# Wordpress page is idle for 25+ seconds and script only take 1 sec to load how to find the delay in oage load

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

I have site on aws windows server and running a wordpress site with the help of xampp, all pages are loading fine but there is one page ("http://13.58.255.34/candidates-list-with-filterable/") this is taking too much time to load.

I have tested it on pingdom and many other sites and it shows that my page is idle for more than 25 secs and load data after that

[image: Page load time]
In above image php scripts are taking some seconds only but in developer console total time taken is 29.37 secs, idle time is 28.73 secs, and page load time is less than 5 secs.

I want my page load time under at least 10 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll level with you.

You're deep in the weeds of bad choices.

First, you should run WordPress no a Linux server, which is it's more native environment.

Additionally if you have long running processes to accumulate the data that would be your slow down.

You would be better served to cache that data in a transient or other rather than updating the data at page load every time.

Finally, even 10 seconds is a very long page load.

You might start with a comprehensive caching plugin and see where it gets you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was setting it up ubuntu but permission issues were there, can you please help me with that

Comment: Honestly I would recommend hosting with Digital Ocean and using the WP install if you want a little dedicated machine. You could also host with something like flywheel and managing your site using local by flywheel would probably make your life a lot easier.